# javascript correctly rounding up to two decimals, impossible?

Tags: javascript, currency, rounding

In php, we have `number_format()`. Passing it a value such as:

```
number_format(3.00 * 0.175, 2);
```

returns **0.53**, which is what I would expect.

However, in JavaScript using `toFixed()`

```
var num = 3.00 * 0.175;
num.toFixed(2);
```

returns **0.52**.

Ok, so perhaps `toFixed` is not what I want...  Maybe something like this...

```
var num = 3.17 * 0.175;
var dec = 2;
Math.round( Math.round( num * Math.pow( 10, dec + 1 ) ) / Math.pow( 10, 1 ) ) / Math.pow(10,dec);
```

No, that doesn't work either. It will return 0.56.

How can I get a `number_format` function in JavaScript that doesn't give an incorrect answer?

Actually I did find an implementation of number_format for js, http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format, but it suffers from the same problem.

What is going on here with JavaScript rounding up? What am I missing?

Comment: In PHP, you're doing 3.00 * 0.175, in your JavaScript 3.17 * 0.175 ..

Comment: Lauri: 3.17 * 0.175 should return 0.55, not 0.56, which is the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, great first question.

Comment: Including two *different* calculations in the question *seriously* dents the usefulness of the question and its answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript does badly with floating point numbers (as do many other languages).

When I run

```
3.000 * 0.175
```

In my browser, I get

```
0.5249999999999999
```

Which will not round up to 0.525 with `Math.round`.  To circumvent this, you kind of have to multiply both sides until you get them to be integers (relatively easy, knowing some tricks help though).

So to do this we can say something like this:

```
function money_multiply (a, b) {
    var log_10 = function (c) { return Math.log(c) / Math.log(10); },
        ten_e  = function (d) { return Math.pow(10, d); },
        pow_10 = -Math.floor(Math.min(log_10(a), log_10(b))) + 1;
    return ((a * ten_e(pow_10)) * (b * ten_e(pow_10))) / ten_e(pow_10 * 2);
}
```

This may look kind of funky, but here's some pseudo-code:

```
get the lowest power of 10 of the arguments (with log(base 10))
add 1 to make positive powers of ten (covert to integers)
multiply
divide by conversion factor (to get original quantities)
```

Hope this is what you are looking for. Here's a sample run:

```
3.000 * 0.175
0.5249999999999999

money_multiply(3.000, 0.175);
0.525
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this is exactly what I was missing. The floating point math had me confused :)

Comment: Yeah, I had to whip out the high school / college knowledge for this one, hahaha.

Comment: btw, figured out Math.log is base of e, not 10, adjusted for future reference

Comment: +1 Nice math.  You could improve this by making using of closures and moving `log_10` and `ten_e` outside of `money_multiply` and into an anonymous function to avoid having to redefine those functions repeatedly.

Comment: *"JavaScript does badly with floating point numbers (as do many other languages)."* Because it's nothing to do with JavaScript, it's IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point that sets the rules. JavaScript (and Java, and so on) just *follow* them.

Answer (score 3):

The `toFixed` function is working correctly. It truncates past the specified amount of fraction digits.

Answer (score 3):

Why all the powers?? Why not just add slightly `less than 1/2 a cent` and `round`:

`(3.00 * 0.175 + 0.0049).toFixed(2)`

Never had any accountants complain about the output.

Comment: The half penny approach always seems to round up. Since I'd like to round half up, less than half down, I compared a run of numbers against the [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round). Here's a comparison of the results.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ledlogic/24a9tkrz/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are encountering is with floating point math as opposed to the rounding itself.

Using the firebug console for testing, logging the result of `3.00 * 0.175` given `0.524999...`. So rounding this number down is actually correct.

I don't know if there is a good solution to your problem, but in my experience when working with currency: it is easier to work in the smallest unit (cents) and then convert for display.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you just use `Math.round( num * Math.pow( 10, dec ) ) / Math.pow( 10, dec) )`?

EDIT: I see, the problem is that 3 * 0.175 gives you 0.52499999999999991, leading you to want an additional rounding step. Maybe just adding a small amount would work:

`Math.round( num * Math.pow( 10, dec ) + 0.000000001 ) / Math.pow( 10, dec) )`

Comment: I actually did try that, but it also returned incorrect results. E.g 3.00 * 0.175 = 0.52. The expression I used was a wacky attempt at trying to force it to give the right answer, but it did not work :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this is how I usually solve a rounding problem. This can be put in a function easily but for now I just put in simple vars for right now. If this doesn't work you could use money_format() or number_format() as a start from php.js (more info below).

```
var n = (3.00 * 0.175);
n = Math.round(n * Math.pow(10, 3)) / Math.pow(10, 3);
Math.round(n*100)/100;
```

comes out to 0.53 (0.5249999999999999)

```
var n = (3.00 * 0.175);
n = Math.round(n * Math.pow(10, 3)) / Math.pow(10, 3);
Math.round(n*100)/100;
```

comes out to 0.56 (0.55475)

It also looks like the php.js repo is being kept up on GitHub https://github.com/kvz/phpjs so if there isn't a function that is not performing correctly an issue can be submitted.

Anyway figured this information may help someone looking later on.